# Python telnetlib read_all hangs until timeout

Tags: python, telnet, telnetlib

I have some Python code that connects via telnet to an OSPF daemon (ran by Quagga) and then does the following:

```
tn.write("show ip ospf database router\n")
tn.write("exit\n")
my_text = tn.read_all()
```

When the output of **show ip ospf database router** is small, the script works fine, but when it is big (approximately 73kb) the code freezes in the **read_all()** call until it timeouts.

My question is: why is this happening? Is there some sort of maximum size of output that read_all can handle?

I should note that if I use **read_very_eager()** instead of **read_all()** the code works fine.

Thank you in advance.
Santiago Vidal.

Answer (score 1):

You can control the size of the output with the following line:

```
               Telnet.set_debuglevel (debuglevel)
```

Set the debug level. The higher the value of debuglevel, the more debug output you get (on sys.stdout).

For example:

```
tn.write("show ip ospf database router\n")
tn.write("exit\n")
my_text = tn.set_debuglevel(1000)
my_text = tn.read_all()
```